# Load font in iOS 11 (or Xcode 9)

Tags: ios, swift, fonts

I have been using `Futura-Demi.otf` font for a while.

With the below code, I could confirm this file contains multiple fonts.

```
for fname in UIFont.familyNames {
    for name in UIFont.fontNames(forFamilyName: fname) {
        print(name)
    }
}
```

Font family is `Futura` and it contains fonts as below:

```
Futura-CondensedExtraBold
Futura-Dem
Futura-Medium
Futura-Bold
Futura-CondensedMedium
Futura-MediumItalic
```

I have used `Futura-Dem` font with `UIFont(name: "Futura-Dem", size: 21)` without any trouble so far. However after iOS 11 is released, I can't use this font anymore. All `Futura-Dem` font are changed to `Futura-Medium` even in the app which already in App Store.

I checked that the font loaded by `UIFont(name: "Futura-Dem", size: 21)` is `Futura-Medium` font and I also found that I can use `Futura-Dem` font with

```
let des = UIFontDescriptor(name: "Futura-Dem", size: 21)
let font = UIFont(descriptor: des, size: 21)
```

The above code loads `Futura-Dem` successfully but I have no idea why I can't just use `UIFont(name: "Futura-Dem", size: 21)` as I did before.

Answer (score 4):

I've had the same issue, with a custom Futura font as well.

I used the software Birdfont ( https://birdfont.org/ *) to rename the font to something different (not starting with Futura, just a single word starting with an upper case). And changing the filename as well but really what was important was to change the font name in the font's meta data.

Then I linked that renamed font to the iOS app and it worked. I don't know why the problem with Futura occurred though, but this trick solved the problem.

*Note: there is also FontForge ( http://fontforge.github.io/en-US/ ) if for some reasons Birdfont doesn't work for you.